# PHP: Loop through json comparing current time with time range based on two keys values

Tags: php, json, unix, epg

I'm basically trying to make an epg viewer based on some json data.

I need some help to figure out how to:

1. Loop through the json data.
2. Get the "start" and "stop" values (unix timestamps) of each program.
3. Make a time range for each program based on the start/stop
   timestamps.
4. Compare the time range of each program with the current unix time.
5. Display the program which has a time range that fits the current time.

**This is what the json data looks like:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "programs": [
            {
                "stop": 1475982300,
                "start": 1475976300,
                "category": "Serier",
                "id": 356532927,
                "title": "KommissÃ¦r Alleyn"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1475983500,
                "start": 1475982300,
                "category": "BÃ¸rn",
                "id": 355997207,
                "title": "UdsendelsesophÃ¸r"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1475985000,
                "start": 1475983500,
                "id": 358595605,
                "title": "DR-Friland: Frilandshaven"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1475986800,
                "start": 1475985000,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 358595606,
                "title": "BonderÃ¸ven 2010"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1475989500,
                "start": 1475986800,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 355933560,
                "title": "Made in Denmark"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1475992500,
                "start": 1475989500,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 357701600,
                "title": "De forunderlige dyr"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1475995500,
                "start": 1475992500,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 358745047,
                "title": "Italien: Fra Sardinien til Abruzzo"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476001200,
                "start": 1475995500,
                "category": "Serier",
                "id": 356295670,
                "title": "Mord pÃ¥ hjernen"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476004800,
                "start": 1476001200,
                "category": "Underholdning",
                "id": 357701601,
                "title": "Puk og Herman gÃ¥r i land - Endelave"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476008100,
                "start": 1476004800,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 355933566,
                "title": "Guld pÃ¥ godset"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476011700,
                "start": 1476008100,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 357701602,
                "title": "Guld pÃ¥ godset"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476017700,
                "start": 1476011700,
                "category": "Serier",
                "id": 356182011,
                "title": "KriminalkommissÃ¦r Barnaby"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476023700,
                "start": 1476017700,
                "category": "Sport",
                "id": 358577056,
                "title": "HÃ¥ndboldSÃ¸ndag: HC Motor Zaporozhye-TTH Holstebro (m), direkte"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476030600,
                "start": 1476023700,
                "category": "Sport",
                "id": 358577057,
                "title": "HÃ¥ndboldSÃ¸ndag: Bjerringbro Silkeborg-THW Kiel (m), direkte"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476032400,
                "start": 1476030600,
                "category": "Nyheder",
                "id": 355933567,
                "title": "TV AVISEN med Sporten og Vejret"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476032700,
                "start": 1476032400,
                "id": 363167503,
                "title": "Guld i KÃ¸bstaden - en hurtig handel"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476036000,
                "start": 1476032700,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 359619002,
                "title": "Atlanterhavet: Verdens vildeste hav"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476039600,
                "start": 1476036000,
                "category": "Serier",
                "id": 355933569,
                "title": "Bedrag II"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476042000,
                "start": 1476039600,
                "category": "Nyheder",
                "id": 355933570,
                "title": "21 SÃ¸ndag"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476042600,
                "start": 1476042000,
                "category": "Sport",
                "id": 358745049,
                "title": "Sporten"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476049200,
                "start": 1476042600,
                "category": "Film",
                "id": 355933571,
                "title": "Killer Elite"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476054600,
                "start": 1476049200,
                "category": "Film",
                "id": 356069380,
                "title": "BlackJack"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476060600,
                "start": 1476054600,
                "category": "Serier",
                "id": 356069381,
                "title": "Taggart: DÃ¸den checker ind"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476066300,
                "start": 1476060600,
                "category": "Film",
                "id": 355933572,
                "title": "MÃ¸rkets gerninger"
            },
            {
                "stop": 1476069000,
                "start": 1476066300,
                "category": "Dokumentar",
                "id": 362546476,
                "title": "DR1 Dokumentar: Danskere omringet af IS"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**This is the PHP I have so far:** *(I know it isn't much. I just don't know how to go on from here)*

```
<?php
$channel = '1';
$current_unix = time();
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://tvtid-app-backend.tv2.dk/api/tvtid/v1/dayviews/'.date('Y-m-d').'?ch='.$channel), true);
$programs = $json[0]['programs'];
$programs_length = count($programs);
for ($i = 0; $i < $programs_length ; $i++)
{
    $begin = [$programs[$i]['start']];
    $end = [$programs[$i]['stop']];
    $title = [$programs[$i]['title']];
}
?>
```

**And this how the output should look:** *(Example time is 16:41)*

```
<ul>
   <li class="program">
      <div class="title_now">TV AVISEN med Sporten og Vejret</div>
      <div class="duration_now">
      <div class="now_begin">16:30</div><span class="begin">1476030600</span>
      <div class="progress_bar"><div class="progress"></div></div>
      <div class="now_end">17:00</div><span class="end">1476032400</span></div>
   </li>
   <li class="program">
      <div class="title">Guld i KÃ¸bstaden - en hurtig handel</div>
      <div class="duration">17:00-17:05</div>
   </li>
   <li class="program">
      <div class="title">Atlanterhavet: Verdens vildeste hav</div>
      <div class="duration">17:05-18:00</div>
   </li>
   <li class="program">
      <div class="title">Bedrag II</div>
      <div class="duration">18:00-19:00</div>
   </li>

   etc...

</ul>
```

I hope this makes sense and that someone is able to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is far simpler using `foreach` to process over a complete array.

```
$channel = '1';
$current_unix = time();

// note I have removed the TRUE option from json_decode()

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://tvtid-app-backend.tv2.dk/api/tvtid/v1/dayviews/'.date('Y-m-d').'?ch='.$channel));
//print_r($json);

echo '<ul>';

foreach ($json as $data) {

    echo '<li>';
    foreach ($data->programs as $prog) {

        if ( $current_unix < $prog->start ) {

            // add your own HTML instead of the simple echo
            echo $prog->title . '<br>';
            echo $prog->start . '<br>';
            echo $prog->stop . '<br>';
            echo $prog->id . '<br>';
            if ( isset($prog->category)) {
                echo $prog->category . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to do a simpler way of processing the json data :)
Would you by any chance also be able to show me how to only echo the program which corresponds with the current time and all the following programs to come? (Not the programs after the current time).

Comment: Sure there you go

Comment: Thank you so very very much @RiggsFolly :) This really saved my day!
Just expanded the if-statement to this `if ( $current_unix < $prog->start || $prog->stop > $current_unix ) {` to display the current program ;)